# How to run GrammarApply offline?

Tags: text, wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy, linguistics

It is a question regarding formal grammar. I have a grammar rule `addition` as below:-

```
addition = 
CloudDeploy[    
GrammarRules[{FixedOrder["add", a : GrammarToken["SemanticNumber"],"and", b : GrammarToken["SemanticNumber"]] :> a + b}]
]
```

And when I apply the grammar rule, I have `13` as output:-

```
GrammarApply[addition, "add six and seven"]
```

But the above codes used `CloudDeploy`. I want to run the code offline (i.e. without using `CloudDeploy`). I tried to remove `CloudDeploy` from `addition` as `addition2` below, but `addition2` doesn't work:-

```
addition2 = 
GrammarRules[{FixedOrder["add", a : GrammarToken["SemanticNumber"],"and", b : GrammarToken["SemanticNumber"]] :> a + b}]

GrammarApply[addition2, "add six and seven"]
```

Error message that I got:-

```
GrammarApply::arg1: The first argument GrammarRules[{FixedOrder[add,a:GrammarToken[SemanticNumber],and,b:GrammarToken[SemanticNumber]]:>a+b}] is expected to be a CloudObject or list of CloudObject.
```

How can I run `GrammarApply` offline? Many thanks!

Comment: It's a good question. It seems likely that this was only meant to work with cloud objects, but the documentation doesn't say that.

Comment: Maybe ask WRI for this feature